# What should I do if an answer does not match the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

I'm asking this question in response to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73663946/13376511). The question asks for help with HTML/CSS/JS, but the answer uses React. Furthermore, this was a late answer, so one could not reasonably think that the question's author was asking about React.

How should I deal with a question like this? I feel like I should flag it, but the closest reasons for flagging are "not an answer" and "very low quality". However, neither of these are true: the answer is an answer, just not for question asked, and the answer is not low quality. Should I simply downvote and move on, or which reason should I use to flag it?

Comment: Is React not a JS library that generates HTML styled with CSS?  Seems responsive to me.  (whether it otherwise correctly answers the question asked, I'm not sure - but the fact that it uses a particular framework doesn't make it non-responsive)

Comment: The question is not (explicitly) about not using any framework, so the answer is valid IMO; if the OP cannot use it, maybe other users can. But the answer itself seems to be low quality (to me), actually just some code, no explanation at all - just downvote it [I'm not JS developer, so maybe I didn't understand the problem]

Comment: *"I feel like I should flag it"* - I like honesty. So let's keep that going. It is important to answer for yourself WHY you feel that way. Because it isn't exactly an event to ignore that you applied sound reasoning, came to a sound conclusion and then threw all of that overboard and created this meta post anyway. There can be only one motivation there - you want this answer dead despite your better judgement.

Comment: Yeah, seems off-topic since question wasn't about doing it in React. Down vote for low quality/off-topic, or now since it's collected some down votes, vote to delete.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not going to guess the intent of the scope of the OP, and presume that they were asking a JavaScript question devoid of other frameworks and/or libraries.

*Inevitably* you run into a JavaScript library somewhere, but I would conjecture that unless the question calls for a solution with that library or framework, it's not...that useful of an answer.

Some of us don't use React, after all.

In this case, I'd say a downvote is enough.  It doesn't answer the question and isn't useful.

Comment: If it is much easier to solve the problem by using react I think it is a useful answer. I'm generally stingy with my downvotes and mostly restrict them to outright wrong information.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica:  Gonna say very loudly that I work on a project with JavaScript that existed when React was still a twinkle in Facebook's eye.  Saying "oh, this is easier with React" to me who has to maintain this ancient thing is simply **not useful**.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica it's only "easier"\* if you're using React. That's not like with jQuery - dragging a whole library for something that can be done without it. Working with React and without React is completely different in terms of how the application would work and how modifications will be done. \*Which brings me to why I used quotes around "easier" - if you're using React, then the rest of the code on the page is not useful to you. For copy/pasting. All the answer does is take the existing way of solving the problem and drape some React code around it to fit it to the ecosystem.

Comment: @Makoto Fair enough. Not all answers are useful to all people -- but many answers are useful to *some* people. It's a bit like asking a C++ question and somebody comes up with a one-liner in boost. Many people are not in a position to use boost, but some are; and to them, it may be an eye-opener.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a huge fan of answers that address the question *title* but ignore the question *body* and *tags*.  I wrote up an entirely different answer to this Meta question based on that distaste, but then had to discard it after realizing that *this* particular question seems to be a bit of a gray area.

The original linked question didn't mention JavaScript at all, just pure HTML/CSS (with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tags only).  The [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom) tags were added three years later in an edit by one of the answerers (who, of course, answered with a JS solution).  Could that mean that the OP was looking for a pure-CSS answer?

The answer, based on the *original* question, appears to be that there *wasn't/isn't* (currently) a pure-HTML/CSS solution to the problem, but that it can be solved with JavaScript.  If that's the case, then is a React solution any "worse" than a pure-JS answer, considering the OP didn't even ask for a pure-JS solution in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Given the asker didn't specify JavaScript wouldn't be acceptable, nor did they specify they wanted a css only solution, I don't see a major problem here. That's not to say you shouldn't see the answer as not useful and cast a downvote, rather, it's not something that needs any form of special treatment. It might have needed some intervention if it was in HNQ and attracting a bunch of useless "Here's a php solution, here's a python solution" etc daily, but we're not at that stage here.

In this case, I'd just continue with the normal process of useful posts get upvoted, not useful ones get downvoted. No need to target it specifically and forbid any non-pure solution.